# Xcode: How to add the built product from one project to another in the same workspace?

Tags: xcode, build, build-process

Say I have 2 projects in an Xcode 4 workspace. Project A is the final product which requires the utility app built from project B. The goal is to have the build process of A automatically build project B if necessary, then copy the built app into the resource folder of product A's app bundle.

Xcode 4's documentation is really lacking in this regard. I tried adding the built B.app into project A with **Add Files to "project A"...** command. It does copy the app bundle but it doesn't check for a dependency. That is, it does not automatically build project B when it's updated.

Any pointer to find the right documentation is also much appreciated.

**Edited:** I am looking to accomplish the first 2 benefits mentioned in this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/NewProject/NewProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH2-SW4), that are:

- One project can use the products of another project while building.
- If one project depends on the products of another in the same
  workspace, Xcode can detect this and automatically build the projects
  in the correct sequence.

I know the plain old project way of adding a project to another one as a sub-project so I can set the target dependencies. But from the wording of the workspace doc, there's seems to be an easier and automatic way. But I am not able to find the steps to do either of the two features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add project B as "Target dependency" in project A's "Build phases" tab in the target screen. (The screen that you get when you click on the top level project node)

**Update:**
It seems that a project can only define the output of another project as dependency if the second project is a subproject of the first:

[image: I can define the output of Project B as dependency of A in this constellation]

If your Workspace has the following structure, defining dependencies is not possible:
[image: Output of B does not show up in the dependency editor of A in this constellation]

Comment: Thanks. But that's like in the plain old project way, right? I thought this new workspace thingy has a better way. In the only doc I find (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/NewProject/NewProject.html) it mentions: "One project can use the products of another project while building." and "If one project depends on the products of another in the same workspace, Xcode can detect this and automatically build the projects in the correct sequence." The later obviously does not really work in my case.

Comment: It seems B must be a subproject of A so that it's output shows up in A's dependency editor. I updated my original answer with screens.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am looking for the new "magical" workspace way. But it seems Apple is just blowing hot air on this one. It's exactly the same old project way. I fail to see the benefit of using the new workspace. Xcode even messes up this old way. It doesn't add product B into the copy resource phase automatically. I have to manually build B and add B.app to A. Even then it still messes it up. I specified the released B to be copied. But when building A for debug, it builds a debug B and can't find B.app to copy since it's in a different build directory. Oh my...

Comment: Yes.Organizing the project as described above was possible without the workspace feature. I also have no idea what advantages one can gain by using workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Step 1 - Create a workspace.
[image]

Step 2 - Drag projects into workspace as siblings
[image]

Step 3 - Add build product of one, as embedded binary, for the other.
[image]

Step 4 - Create code, stating public where necessary.
[image]

Step 5 - Use the code
[image]

Comment: The OP wanted to add built products, not source files, which is what will be in the Project B dir.

Comment: @ScottMarks this answer is like a millions years old. Will update the answer in a minute.